# Help on script for parametric surface integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm working on a short script that I can repeatedly use to solve parametric surface integrals. There is a post on this elsewhere on MSE, but it is a complicated doublecontourintegral function. It is impossible to parse for a newcomer like me, and it seems possible to create something more simple.

Here's an example problem:

Find the surface integral of $(x + y + s)dS$, where S is the parallelogram with parametric equations $x = u + v$; $y = u - v$; $z = 1 + 2u + v$; and $0 \leq u \leq 2$, $0 \leq v \leq 1$.

So I wanted to write a script that I can just type in the non-parametrized equation, i.e., $(x + y + s)$ in this example. Then I'd enter in the parameters for x, y, and z (given in this problem).

Next, I'd take the partial derivatives with respect to u an v of the parametrized equation.

Next, I'd cross product those two partial derivatives and find its magnitude, using **Norm**.

Next, I'd re-parametrize $(x + y + s)$.

Finally, I'd integrate the re-paremetrized surface, multiplied by the magnitude of the partials, over the region, given in this problem as $0 \leq u \leq 2$, $0 \leq v \leq 1$.

I am new to Mathematica, and I started this sequence with the following code, but it doesn't seem to work. I'd welcome any help.

```
Clear[x, y, u, v]
x[u_, v_] := u + v;
y[u_, v_ ] := u - v;
z[u_, v_] := 1 + 2 u + v;
R[u_, v_] := {x[u_, v_], y[u_, v_], z[u_, v_]}
```

UPDATE: This code works well on problems I've tried.  But I'm having trouble with another problem. The book answer is 1/(10sqrt(2)). I'm attaching as a picture its worked example. But both of your methods give 1/5sqrt(2). Did I miss something? Is the book in error? Here's the code I used, and the book's answer.

```
x[u_, v_] := u Cos[v];
y[u_, v_] := u Sin[v];
z[u_, v_] := u;
r[u_, v_] := {x[u, v], y[u, v], z[u, v]};
reg = ParametricRegion[r[u, v], {{u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, Pi/2}}];
Integrate[x y z, {x, y, z} \[Element] reg]
```

And here's is the book answer, which is Problem 6:

[image]

Comment: `1/(5 Sqrt[2]) == Sqrt[2]/10`

Comment: Of course it is. Drrr. Apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x[u_, v_] := u + v;
y[u_, v_] := u - v;
z[u_, v_] := 1 + 2 u + v;
r[u_, v_] := {x[u, v], y[u, v], z[u, v]};
Integrate[(x[u, v] + y[u, v] + z[u, v]) Norm@
   Cross[D[r[u, v], u], D[r[u, v], v]], {u, 0, 2}, {v, 0, 1}]
```

> `11 Sqrt[14]`

Or

```
x[u_, v_] := u + v;
y[u_, v_] := u - v;
z[u_, v_] := 1 + 2 u + v;
r[u_, v_] := {x[u, v], y[u, v], z[u, v]};
 reg =ParametricRegion[r[u, v], {{u, 0, 2}, {v, 0, 1}}];
Integrate[x + y + z, {x, y, z} ∈ reg]
```

> `11 Sqrt[14]`

Comment: Thanks so much for the code. It is very helpful. See my update above, if you can, and perhaps you can clarify?

Comment: And this code doesn't seem (?) to work if the parameters are trig functions. I get strange message when I use trig functions in the parameters. Is that right?

Comment: @BRC You can use  Clear["`*"]; to clear  the variable before the new evaluation.

Comment: I tried that, alas. If you make the integrand something with just one variable, would that make the code unworkable? For example, in a similar problem to "Update' above, I changed the integrand to just "y" and it gave me gobbledygook: 
\!\(\*UnderscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \({x, y, z} \[Element] 
   ParametricRegion[{{Cos[v]\ u, u\ Sin[v], v}, 
     0 \[LessEqual] u \[LessEqual] 1 && 
      0 \[LessEqual] v \[LessEqual] 
\*FractionBox[\(\[Pi]\), \(2\)]}, {u, v}]\)]\)y

Comment: Perhaps if I just have a single (or even two )variable in the integrand (all of the other problems had x, y, and z), I need some kind of placeholder for the missing variable?

Comment: @BRC `x[u_, v_] := u + v;
y[u_, v_] := u - v;
r[u_, v_] := {x[u, v], y[u, v]};
reg = ParametricRegion[r[u, v], {{u, 0, 2}, {v, 0, 1}}];
Integrate[x + y, {x, y} \[Element] reg]`

Comment: Thanks so much for your generous time and effort. But the integrand in your problem is x + y. What if it is just "y"? As in the following, which doesn't compute: x[u_, v_] := u Cos[v];
y[u_, v_] := u Sin[v];
z[u_, v_] := v;
r[u_, v_] := {x[u, v], y[u, v], z[u, v]};
reg = ParametricRegion[r[u, v], {{u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, Pi/2}}];
Integrate[y, {x, y, z} \[Element] reg]

Comment: @BRC We can use `NIntegrate` instead of `Integrate` to calculate the numeric value. `x[u_, v_] := u Cos[v]; y[u_, v_] := u Sin[v]; z[u_, v_] := v; 
r[u_, v_] := {x[u, v], y[u, v], z[u, v]}; reg = 
 ParametricRegion[r[u, v], {{u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, Pi/2}}]; NIntegrate[y, 
 Element[{x, y, z}, reg]]`

Comment: Many thanks. I'm sincerely grateful.